# WinAPI Message Queue example

Tags: c, windows, winapi, client-server, message-queue

Does anyone know where can I find a simple client/server WinAPI message queue example?

I'd like to create a program that sends data from a client to a server using message queues and I can't find anything useful on the web.

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you want two different programs communicating with each other. I don't believe message queues, as defined in Windows API (PostMessage/SendMessage), are used for inter-process communication. Uses pipes or other such [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) means.

Comment: @Lundin He likely means [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx) samples.

Comment: @WhozCraig Aah right, well there we go then, [RTFMSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms705205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :)

Comment: @Lundin: the `WM_COPYDATA` window message can be used for inter-process communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WM_COPYDATA` message can be used, but only synchronously. Without using `MSMQ`, you'd have to implement your own message queue using named shared memory & named semaphores for asynchronous queues.